# Minimize code for getElementById / getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have 2 blocks of code that originally forms 120 lines of code with a lot of repitions. I also foresee that the code lines will grow. Below you find a minimal extraction.

**Question:**

Is it possible to iterate over [getElementById] and [getElementsByClassName] ?

Or should I break up the text in strings and construct new strings using variables?

Could "template literals" be a solution by embedding expressions in the strings?

---

There are some difference in the lines that needs to change: The number, the subset [x] and "block"/"none".

```
function display_page_2_button_1() {
    document.getElementById("show_services_inline_1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("show_services_inline_2").style.display = "none";
}

function display_page_4_button_1() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("show_demos_inline_1")[0].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("show_demos_inline_1")[1].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("show_demos_inline_2")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("show_demos_inline_2")[1].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you can use string literals for this.

Long answer:
If possible I would change the setup slightly to have all the elements include a more generic class (show_demos_inline) or use a data attribute and querySelecrorAll, which you can then iterate over.
Using some simple logic could then differentiate between block/none depending on what you are trying to do.  Proably you only want one element to show? You could pass some identifier for this element to the function and check on it during the loop.

Comment: That is correct. Only one element should be visible at a time, and the rest hidden.

Comment: What you are trying to make is usually called an 'Accordion'.  There are several ways to implement, one easy and quick one is to actually store the currently open block in a variable and have the event that triggers the toggle close the currently open, set it to the new and open that one.  A very basic rudimentary implementation can be found here: https://codepen.io/svanraes/pen/BaBVMOq

Answer (score 0):

Below code minimize the amount of code lines (assuming that the startpoint is +120 lines). It also copes with growth of amount of divs.

A function is created at the beginning of the script to first close all divs. Each [display_page_2_button_X] function then only make one div visible.

It use "template literals" to adapt the code so that I can run the string in a for-loop.

**The code for [services]:**

```
service = "show_services_inline_";

function hide_all_services_div() {
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        document.getElementById(`${service}${i}`).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function display_page_2_button_1() {
    hide_all_services_div();
    document.getElementById(`${service}1`).style.display = "block";
}
```

**The code for [demos]:**

```
demo = "show_demos_inline_";

function hide_all_demos_div() {
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${demo}${i}`)[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${demo}${i}`)[1].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function display_page_4_button_1() {
    hide_all_demos_div();
    document.getElementsByClassName(`${demo}1`)[0].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName(`${demo}1`)[1].style.display = "block";
}
```